# not rendering by using query parameter in react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using react-router-dom v6

currently,  it works well (successfully rendering reviewTab) below code

```js
 <NavLink to='reviews' >reviewTab </NavLink>
   ~~
     <Routes>
            <Route path="reviews" element={<ReviewTab />}></Route>
     </Routes>
```

and I want to add pagination this ReviewTab. so I just add queryParameter `reviews?page=1` like below code

```js
 <NavLink to='reviews?page=1' >reviewTab </NavLink>
   ~~
     <Routes>
            <Route path="reviews?page=1" element={<ReviewTab />}></Route>
     </Routes>
```

and it cannot render ReviewTab. what is the reason about this error?

Answer (score 0):

I think the Route should be wrapped with Routes and Routes should be wrapped with BrowserRoute. i think that why you are getting the error. try the code below and check if it works.

```
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";
...,
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
     <Route path="reviews?page=1" element={<ReviewTab />}></Route>
   </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! I  already put the BrowserRoute element. but I solved the problem just adding '*'. have a good day

Answer (score 0):

I knew that the Route path should be add '*'. so, below the code, it works!

```
<NavLink to='reviews?page=1' >reviewTab </NavLink>
   ~~
     <Routes>
            <Route path="reviews/*" element={<ReviewTab />}></Route>
     </Routes>
```